# Changing switch statement to if statement

Tags: android, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to change this switch statement to if statement or while loop.
How can I do that?
Note this piece of code using Android Studio.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.button:
        Log.v(TAG, "verbose");
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        Log.d(TAG, "Debug");
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        Log.i(TAG, "Information");
        break;
    case R.id.button4:
        Log.w(TAG, "Warning");
        break;
    case R.id.button5:
        Log.e(TAG,"Error");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand the issue, instead of a switch just use if's

Comment: switch case here its an good choice why you want if...else

Comment: if is used to select bn 2 options and switch is used among multiple options.Also performance of switch is better in case of multiple option.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use existing `switch` statement, but if you really want `if`, you can do it like this:

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.button) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Verbose");
    } else if (id == R.id.button2) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Debug");
    } else if (id == R.id.button3) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Information");
    } else if (id == R.id.button4) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Warning");
    } else if (id == R.id.button5) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error");
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using AndroidStudio, you could use intent

1. Place your cursor on the `switch` keyword
2. Press `alt+enter` (on Mac, not sure about Windows)
3. Select `Replace 'switch' with 'if'`

Note: You could replace if to switch using the same method.